# How can I debug the plotting and printing part of an octave script

Tags: linux, debugging, plot, octave, archlinux

Suppose I have an octave script which is supposed to compute and plot a few curves; it runs cleanly but the plots do not look as they are supposed to.

Suppose I see unwanted behaviors like:

- subplots not on the same figure (only the last subplot);
- subscripts in legends only correctly shown in the octave figure, not in the resulting pdf

Suppose further that I know that it worked in the past - though with another version of any programs involved including octave, the linux kernel, any pdf-printing device programs etc.

How should I go about finding out what is going on? Is there a way of forcing octave to give verbose output about this? 
The script used the `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")` and printing device pdf (`print( (...) -dpdf (...)`). Octave version is 4.0.3, linux kernel is 4.7.6, distribution is Arch Linux.
Octave debug mode (running the script as `octave -d <script>` does not seem to produce anything identifiably related to printing or plotting.)

EDIT: As a very crude way of debugging a pause(1) command can be inserted at various points to get a closer look at what the figure looks like at these stages. It turns out that it is only the `print()` command that destroys the layout. Until right before that everything looks fine. However, I am still no closer to understanding how to finding a way of figuring out what goes wrong with the print command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the latest release candidate (rc3) from ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/octave/

To debug printing issues with gnuplot try

```
print("testplot.eps", "-debug")
```

and inspect the generated octave-print-commands.log, debug messages and testplot.eps. And of course it would be best if you can create a minimalistic example. What gnuplot version do you use?